# ubuntu can not detect my Sony MDR-ZX330BT HEADSET bluetooth

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, sony, headset

my laptop can not detect my bluetooth HEADSET, i can detect others devices but not my headset.

Comment: Are you sure your headset is in discoverable mode?

Comment: yes i can detect him with my phone and it s working

Answer (score 5):

You need to press and hold the POWER button **for more than 7 seconds**. Make sure that the indicator flashes blue and red alternately after you release the button. That's how you connect it on ubuntu.

Cheers :)

Comment: thank you so muuuuch!